# What does Chio mean in S3E03?

Tags: dialogue, hannibal-tv

In *Hannibal* S03E03 Chio, an Asian woman, says to Will:

> I need to press the trigger 3 pounds. I'm pressing 2.

What does she mean? That she is currently pressing 2 pounds or at most 2 pounds?

Comment: No, that's not what she said. She said "This trigger has a three-pound pull. I'm holding two of it."

Comment: @BCdotWEB I wasn't watching it in English. So the translation wasn't very exact here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means she's about to pull the trigger...that it won't take much more to pull it.